# Explanation of this method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
public class A {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print(" A1");
    }

    public void method2() {
        method1();
        System.out.print(" A2");
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void method2() {
        super.method2();
        System.out.print(" B2");
    }

    public void method1() {
        System.out.print(" B1");
    }
}

public class B2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B();
        b.method2();
    }
}
```

Why does the `method1()` call inside class `A`'s `method2()` call `method1()` of class `B` instead of `method1()` of class `A`?

Comment: I could not get your question!

Answer (score 3):

`method1()` of class `B` overrides `method1()` of class `A`, so calling `method1()` on an instance whose runtime type is `B` will execute `method1()` of class `B`. It doesn't matter that the call to `method1()` is done from a method of class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

method1() from class B is called because the "this" reference  refers to Object of type B() while calling

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the code,`super.method2()` is simply calling `method2()` from the class `A`.

So try to simplify everything by making the substitution with copy and paste; this way class `B` becomes:

```
public class B extends A {
    public void method2() {
        method1();
        System.out.print(" A2");
        System.out.print(" B2");
    }

    public void method1() {
       System.out.print(" B1");
    }
}
```

Here you can clearly see that when the line `b.method2()` is run, it will run in order top to bottom:

1. `method1()` - This will print " B1"
2. Print " A2"
3. Print " B2"

I hope this explains a little more.